# Best notation for defining a specific vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

I want to write down a formal definition of a specific vector space. It is my understanding that a vector space is a set of vectors that adhere to the eight axioms of associativity, commutativity etc.

The vector space I want to write down has the following properties:

1. It is an infinite line
2. The line is in $\mathbb R^n$ space
3. The vectors have n components in $\mathbb R$

This is what I have so far, but I think it's wrong, because the vectors could point in any direction not just along a line:

$$\mathbb S = \{c\textbf{v} \mid c \in \mathbb{R}\ \text{ and }\ \textbf{v} = \langle v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3} \rangle\ \text{and}\ v_{1}\, v_{2}, v_{3} \in \mathbb R \}$$

What is the correct way to write this down please?

Comment: Additional disclosure: I don't have any knowledge of fields, other than we define a vector space "over" a field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With what you have written, $\Bbb S$ is actually equal to $\Bbb R^3$; indeed, you allow $v_1,v_2,v_3$ to vary in $\Bbb R$. The correct way to define a line is to fix a certain vector $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, and to define $\Bbb S=\{cv\mid 
c\in \Bbb R\}$. Sometimes this is also denoted $\Bbb Rv$.

Comment: Arnaud: I've edited to change the "|" in your set notation to "\mid", which gives a little space on either side of the bar, and is easier to read. (After 30 years of using latex, I just learned this a couple of years ago!)

Comment: @JohnHughes I'd seen people use this, but I didn't know it added some space. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Here it is with mid: $\{a\mid a < 2\}$ and without: $\{a| a < 2\}$.

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudD. that's helpful. When defining the invariant vector $\textbf{v}$, how do I clarify that $v_{1}, v_{2},v_{3}$ are constant elements of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Jinglesting You can write something like "Let $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)\in \Bbb R^3$.", or "Let us consider a fixed vector $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)\in \Bbb R^3$" if you want to insist.